# (Perl) Create query for DBI with SQL::Abstract

Tags: sql, perl, sqlite, perl-module, dbi

I want to add new record to table1 on SQLite

```
use SQL::Abstract;
my %data = (
  id => \'max(id)', # it is doesn't work so which variant is right?
  record => 'Something'
);

my $sql = SQL::Abstract->new;

my ($stmt, @bind) = $sql->insert('table1', \%data);


...
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($stmt);
```

If I used DBIx::Class in Catalyst app I would written like so:

`id => $c->model('Model')->get_column('id')->max()`

and it will work fine.
So how can I reach the same aim but using just SQL::Abstract which is used in DBIx::Class as well.
Could someone fixed it? Thanks.

Comment: That seems really inefficient.  Why not make the column auto-increment or use a counters table?

Comment: It's also subject to race conditions if you have more than 1 process doing inserts.

Comment: I just wanna understand how to use this module for making complicated queries.

Comment: Think backwards - what do you think the SQL should look like? Can you do this in one step or does it have to be two (finding the max id and then inserting new record)? How do you find the max id (is it a function call or a separate SQL)? It may just not be the best use case for this Perl module.

Comment: Caveat: i don't use this perl module, but maybe you're looking for the syntax for calling SQL functions: http://search.cpan.org/~frew/SQL-Abstract-1.73/lib/SQL/Abstract.pm#Inserting_and_Updating_SQL

Comment: @theglauber I read it but I've came upon with this problem when I've tried do it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a piece of code. As you can see, first you need to get the max id+1 and then do the insert command. I have to notice you this is not safe, because in a multi-(user,process,thread) environment, a second process can execute the same code and get race conditions.
But I assume you are just learning the SQL::Abstract api, and that problem doesn't matter

```
use DBI;
use SQL::Abstract;

#create table TEST(ID integer, NAME varchar);
my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:SQLite:dbname=test.db', '', '', {AutoCommit=>1});

my $sql = SQL::Abstract->new;

my($stmt, @bind) = $sql->select("TEST", [ 'max(ID)+1 as ID' ] );
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($stmt);
$sth->execute(@bind);

my ($id) = $sth->fetchrow_array // 1;

print "Select ID: $id", "\n";
$sth->finish;

($stmt, @bind) = $sql->insert("TEST", { ID=>$id, NAME=>"test-name"} );
$sth = $dbh->prepare($stmt);
$sth->execute(@bind);

$dbh->disconnect;
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. You showed me a variant which consist of two steps but I would like do the same thing by one step. Something like this: `id => { -in => \'select max(id) from table1' }`